# How to parse data from multiple URLs using asyncTask

Tags: android

The main problem is I'm unable to return two value help. i have tried lot of time but no success. And guys I'm new to this so please write your answer with respect to my code thanks in advance.

Here's my code

```
    public class calculate extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                uss = getJson("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22INRUSD%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=");
                JSONObject usjObj;
                usjObj = new JSONObject(uss);
                usResult = usjObj.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONObject("rate").getString("Rate");


                eurr = getJson("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22INREUR%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=");
                JSONObject eurjObj;
                eurjObj = new JSONObject(eurr);
                eurResult = eurjObj.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONObject("rate").getString("Rate");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return eurResult + usResult;
            ////PROBLEM IS HERE ACTUALLY I DON'T KNOW HOW TO RETURN TWO OR MORE VALUE/////"
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String usResult) {
            valueus = Double.parseDouble(usResult);
            inputus = lengthvalue * valueus;
            us.setText("" + inputus);

            valueeur = Double.parseDouble(eurResult);
            inputeur = lengthvalue * valueeur;
            eur.setText("" + inputeur);
        }

    }


    public String getJson(String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String con;
        while ((con = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            build.append(con);
        }
        return build.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, you need to learn to write good questions - do read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in help.  Only include relevant code, not your entire code dump.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to cram everything into a `String`.  There are better data structures to hold multiple values: array, Vector, List, etc.  Declare your AsyntTask as:

```
public class calculate extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]>
```

and then your `doInBackgorund` method would be something like this:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String[] result = new String[numResults];

    ...
    result[0] = usjObj.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONObject("rate").getString("Rate");

    ...
    result[1] = usjObj.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONObject("rate").getString("Rate");

    ...

    return result;
}
```

And finally your `onPostExecute` would be

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] usResult) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks just tell me where to add my urls

Comment: That you will have to figure out by yourself.